# Punctuation loading "animation", javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a good way to display some punctuation loading "animation".

What I want is something like this:

```
This will display at second 1: "Waiting for your input."
This will display at second 2: "Waiting for your input.."
This will display at second 3: "Waiting for your input..."
This will display at second 4: "Waiting for your input...."
This will display at second 5: "Waiting for your input."
This will display at second 6: "Waiting for your input.."
This will display at second 7: "Waiting for your input..."
This will display at second 8: "Waiting for your input...."
```

And so on.

I started by surrounding the dots in `spans` and thought I could loop through them with jquery and display one more, one more, one more, then reset to 1. But the code got very clumsy, so I wonder how you would do this?

Comment: Use key-frames animation, with an ::after element with different content perhaps..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The trick to making a string of dots is to make a sparse Array and then join all the elements with the desired character.

```
var count = 0;
setInterval(function(){
    count++;
    var dots = new Array(count % 10).join('.');
    document.getElementById('loadingtext').innerHTML = "Waiting for your input." + dots;
  }, 1000);
```

Here is a [Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ty4gt/).

Comment: You could also pre-cache the dot strings to avoid recreating the array on each iteration (but then again the performance gain may be minimal).

Comment: Works treat.  I'm not a major fan of shorthand though it reduces the readability.  What does `count % 10` mean?

Comment: `%` is the modulo operator, which is basically the remainder. You can find it in many languages. I wouldn't call it shorthand, it's just a a numerical operator like `+` or `/`. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Comment: with new Date().getSeconds() % 10 you don't need the count variable

Answer (score 20):

## Pure CSS solution

Demo: [jsfiddle.net/feklee/D59P9](http://jsfiddle.net/feklee/D59P9/)

- HTML:

  ```
  Waiting<span class="dots"><span>.</span><span>.</span><span>.</span></span> for more.
  ```
- CSS:

  ```
  @keyframes dots-1 { from { opacity: 0; } 25% { opacity: 1; } }
  @keyframes dots-2 { from { opacity: 0; } 50% { opacity: 1; } }
  @keyframes dots-3 { from { opacity: 0; } 75% { opacity: 1; } }
  @-webkit-keyframes dots-1 { from { opacity: 0; } 25% { opacity: 1; } }
  @-webkit-keyframes dots-2 { from { opacity: 0; } 50% { opacity: 1; } }
  @-webkit-keyframes dots-3 { from { opacity: 0; } 75% { opacity: 1; } }

  .dots span {
      animation: dots-1 1s infinite steps(1);
      -webkit-animation: dots-1 1s infinite steps(1);
  }

  .dots span:first-child + span {
      animation-name: dots-2;
      -webkit-animation-name: dots-2;
  }

  .dots span:first-child + span + span {
      animation-name: dots-3;
      -webkit-animation-name: dots-3;
  }
  ```

## WebKit-only alternative

Advantage: No nested tags. This means that the ellipsis could be put as content
into an `::after` pseudo element.

Demo: [jsfiddle.net/feklee/vFT7W](http://jsfiddle.net/feklee/vFT7W/)

- HTML:

  ```
  Waiting<span>...</span> for more.
  ```
- CSS:

  ```
  body {
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      font-size: 50px;
  }

  @-webkit-keyframes dots {
      0% { background-position: 0px; }
      100% { background-position: 50px; }
  }

  span {
      background: linear-gradient(to right, white 50%, black 50%);
      color: transparent;
      -webkit-background-clip: text;
      -webkit-animation: dots 1s infinite steps(4);
      padding-right: 40px;
      margin-right: -40px;
  }
  ```

Comment: Waiting for your input <span>...</span>

Comment: Nice job with the CSS solution.

Answer (score 3):

This can be very easy:

**HTML**

```
<span class="dots"></span>
```

**JQuery**

```
setInterval(function() {
    var th = $('.dots');
    if(th.text().length < 5){
        th.text(th.text()+".");
    }else{
        th.text("");
    }
}, 500);
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/chalist/65Lyup35/)

Answer (score 1):

Now sure how the code got out of hand, you could just do:

```
setInterval(function () {
  var span = $("#text-loader").children("span:eq(0)");
  var ellipsis = span.html();
  ellipsis = ellipsis + ".";
  if (ellipsis.length > 5) {
    ellipsis = ".";
  }
  span.html(ellipsis);
}, 1000);

<div id="text-loader">
  This will display at second 1: "Waiting for your input<span>.</span>
</div>
```

And as for the `1`, you can swap that out with the number of periods.

Answer (score 0):

try this function: i'v put an example here http://jsfiddle.net/XFd39/

```
var i=0;   
function f() {
if(i<=4)
 $('#a').append(".");
i++;
if(i==4){
    $('#a').html("");
    i=0;
}
setTimeout(f,500);
}
f();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pretty simple variant: http://jsfiddle.net/psycketom/FusdC/

Read the comments below to understand what everything is doing there.

```
var span = $('.dots'); // take the element where you have the maximum count of dots
var text = span.text(); // cahce it's text value

// we set up a function here, so we can loop it all the time
var loading = function()
{
    $({
        count : 1 // we start at one dot
    }).animate({
        count : text.length // together forming all of it
    }, {
        duration : 1000, // make the animation complete in one second
        step : function() {
            span.text( text.substring(0, Math.round(this.count)) ); // on each step, change the text accordingly to current iteration
        },
        complete : function() {
            loading(); // once complete, start all over again
        }
    });
};

loading(); // start it up for the first time
```

Here you also gain the advantage of using `easing` if you wish, easily changing total duration and bunch of other benefits in case you're good with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Dude, unless you want to display this animation *forever* you will need a way to stop the animation, or?

Don't even think about global variables, this is **JavaScript** and it's got closures for that :)

```
<p>please wait<span id="wait"></span></p>

<input type="submit" id="start" value="start">
<input type="submit" id="stop" value="stop">

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var animator = function($el) {
            var dotCount = 1;
            var started = true;
            return {
                "start" : function step() {
                    dotCount = (dotCount + 1) % 10;
                    $el.text(new Array(dotCount).join('.'));
                    if (started) {
                        setTimeout(step, 100);
                    }
                },
                "stop" : function() {
                    started = false;
                }
            }
        };

        var animatedWait = animator($("#wait"));

        $("#start").click(animatedWait.start);
        $("#stop").click(animatedWait.stop);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modified version that will turn off the dots after a time.

```
var count = 0;
var dots = setInterval(function(){
  count++;
  document.getElementById('loadingtext').innerHTML = "Waiting for your input." + new Array(count % 5).join('.');

  if (count == 10){ // show two iterations of the array.
    clearInterval(dots); // stop the dots.
  }
}, 100); // sets the speed
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ty4gt/331/